# Firebase Realtime Database is slower than local MySQL Server

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/fireblog/users");

        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                User newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                System.out.println("Username: " + newPost.getUsername());
                long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
                System.out.println("elapsedTime=" + elapsedTime);
            }

            // ...
        });
```

It takes at least 2 seconds to read the node's data. But with local MySQL it only takes approximately 200 milliseconds. It only happens on the first time and then they will read super fast. Why? So what's the point of using Firebase realtime database? Can I upload the whole web app to Firebase and get it faster?

Comment: I wrote the most basic answer below. But to be honest, this question is way too broad. If this is really a comparison you want to pursue, aim for feature parity in your example. So show how you do the same thing with mySQL, and then compare the two (in terms of cost, effort, scalability, etc). It may well be that mySQL is the better choice for your use-case, but only you can decide that.

Comment: this is too much.

Comment: If that code is taking 2 seconds, you've got a bigger issue, possibly an internet connection problem or something else in the code; that really should take .02 seconds (it does for me). Additionally, comparing an *online* database against a local server doesn't really work - it's two different animals; Firebase can have thousands of users from around the world, a *local* SQL server typically won't. Do you need a live, event-driven, online, multi-user database? If not then a local server may be a better solution. As you can see it's impossible to compare without understanding your use case.

Answer (score 2):

At a very minimum: Firebase will automatically monitor `server/saving-data/fireblog/users` for changes, and call your `onChild...` methods when the data changes. This requires that it keeps an open connection between the server and the client, which a default MySQL installation will not do.